# Changing background color from TEXT WIDGET not possible?

Tags: python, text, tkinter, colors, widget

I excercise on a simple text editor with a simple menu point called "Colorsheme", to change the backgroud color of a text widget (e.g. like darkmode or lightmode).

When i use my own script (for me it looks logical), I do not get the desired result. The backgroundcolor does not change!

Here is the script. May you have some hints for me?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from tkinter import *

col_bg = "white"
col_fg = "grey"

fenster = Tk()
fenster.title("Hello Windowtitle")
fenster.geometry("500x300")
fenster.configure(background="white")


# Definition Text widget
def buildnew_textwidget(col_bg,col_fg):
    T = Text(fenster, height=300, width=200, bg=col_bg, fg=col_fg, bd=0)
    T.pack()
    T.insert(END, "")
buildnew_textwidget(col_bg, col_fg)


# Definition Colors
def Rot():
    col_bg = "red"
    col_fg = "black"
    buildnew_textwidget(col_bg, col_fg)

def Gelb():
    col_bg = "yellow"
    col_fg = "black"
    buildnew_textwidget(col_bg, col_fg)

menu = Menu(fenster)

# Colorsheme
colorsheme = Menu(menu, tearoff=0, background='black',
foreground='#D9CB9E', activebackground='#D9CB9E',
activeforeground='#374140', activeborderwidth=4)

menu.add_cascade(label="Colorsheme", menu=colorsheme)
colorsheme.add_command(label="Rot", command=Rot)
colorsheme.add_command(label="Gelb", command=Gelb)

fenster.config(menu=menu)

mainloop( )
```

Comment: Hi, Oliver, if my answer answered your question and if you think it is correct, please, mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the structure a little bit. In order to change the color use: T["bg"] = col_bg and T["fg"] = col_fg

Also, if your T (text element) is static, it is better not to create if within event method

```
from tkinter import *

col_bg = "white"
col_fg = "grey"

fenster = Tk()
fenster.title("Hello Windowtitle")
fenster.geometry("500x300")
fenster.configure(background="white")


# Definition Text widget
def buildnew_textwidget(col_bg,col_fg):
    T["bg"] = col_bg
    T["fg"] = col_fg
    T.insert(END, "")

T = Text(fenster, height=300, width=200, bg=col_bg, fg=col_fg, bd=0)
T.pack()

# Definition Colors
def Rot():
    col_bg = "red"
    col_fg = "black"
    buildnew_textwidget(col_bg, col_fg)

def Gelb():
    col_bg = "yellow"
    col_fg = "black"
    buildnew_textwidget(col_bg, col_fg)

menu = Menu(fenster)

# Colorsheme
colorsheme = Menu(menu, tearoff=0, background='black',
foreground='#D9CB9E', activebackground='#D9CB9E',
activeforeground='#374140', activeborderwidth=4)

menu.add_cascade(label="Colorsheme", menu=colorsheme)
colorsheme.add_command(label="Rot", command=Rot)
colorsheme.add_command(label="Gelb", command=Gelb)

fenster.config(menu=menu)

mainloop( )
```

Comment: I am sooooo thankfull for that hint Olia! It works perfectly now!
Dankeschön! m(＿＿)m

I think i have to think different structured now! :-)

Comment: @Oliver , Bitterschön!. it is always good to improve. Please, mark the answer correct, If it helped